# angularJs sorting code doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I totally cant understand, why my sorting code doesn't work.
I want just add a sorting method "sortFlag" to my app, and it doesn't work in a right way.

Here is code:

```
var App2 = angular.module('App2',[
    //submodules
]);

    App2.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/14fug5')
        .success(function(datas){
            $scope.datas_1 = datas
            console.log($scope.datas_1.schema);

        });
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/q80it')
        .success(function(datas){
            $scope.datas_2 = datas
        });

        // $scope.predicate = '';
        // $scope.reverse = true;
        // $scope.order = function(predicate) {
        //     $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
        //     $scope.predicate = predicate;
        // };

        $scope.sortFlag = 'id';
        $scope.sortTable = function(flag){
            $scope.sortFlag = flag;
        }

    }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" ng-app="App2">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>angular example 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
        integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div ng-init>

    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchFish">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<div ng-controller="MainController">
    <span>выберите данные:</span>
    <span>данные1</span>
    <input
        name="content"
        type="radio"
        ng-model="content"
        ng-init="content='first'"
        value="first"
    />
    <span>данные2</span>
    <input
        name="content"
        type="radio"
        ng-model="content"
        value="second"
    />


<table ng-show="content == 'first'">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in datas_1.schema">
            <button href="#"
                    ng-click="sortTable('{{key}}')">
                    <!--ng-show="predicate === '{{key}}'"-->
                    <!--ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"-->

                {{value}}
            </button>
        </th>

        <!--<th>-->
        <!--<button href="#"-->
        <!--ng-click="order('{{key}}')"-->
        <!--ng-show="predicate === '{{key}}'"-->
        <!--ng-class="{reverse:reverse}">{{datas_1.schema.id}}</button>-->
        <!--</th>-->
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in datas_1.data | orderBy: sortFlag">
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.price}}</td>
        <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table ng-show="content == 'second'">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key, value) in datas_2.schema">
            <button href="#" ng-click="order('{{key}}')">{{value}}</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in datas_2.data | orderBy: sortFlag">
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.price}}</td>
        <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>


    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

if you have any idea, please help me with this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the `orderBy` can take a scope variable to use a sorting field. You should use a function instead.

controller :

```
$scope.dynamicOrderFunction = function() {
    return '-' + $scope.sortFlag;
}
```

You can change the - sign with a plus sign depending on the direction of your sorting.

template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas_2.data | orderBy: dynamicOrderFunction">
    <td>{{data.id}}</td>
    <td>{{data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{data.price}}</td>
    <td>{{data.quantity}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add another parameter "reverse" to your orderBy in ng-repeat something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in datas_2.data | orderBy:sortFlag:reverse">
```

And to your function in controller set the boolean value to that reverse parameter.

```
$scope.sortFlag = 'id';
$scopr.reverse = false;
$scope.sortTable = function(flag){
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.sortFlag === flag) ? 
     !$scope.reverse : false;
    $scope.sortFlag = flag;
}
```

This should solve your problem. Let me know if it doesn't work for you.